# Make my python's Bluetooth server visible to iOS

Tags: python, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I've been struggling to connect a Bluetooth server (using Bluez or similar) in a Python script which runs on a Linux service, with an iPhone device which runs a Cordova hybrid app.

I'm using cordova-plugin-ble-central for the latter, and for the former I give you the code below:

```
try:
    server_sock = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)

    server_sock.bind(("", 0))
    server_sock.listen(1)
    port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

    uuid = "d507688e-5fa7-11e7-907b-a6006ad3dba0"
    advertise_service(server_sock, "TestService", service_id=uuid, service_classes=[uuid])

    print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

    client_sock, address = server_sock.accept()
    print "Accepted connection from ", address

    data = client_sock.recv(1024)
    print "received [%s]" % data

    client_sock.close()
    server_sock.close()
except Exception as e:
    print 'ERROR: ' + str(e)
```

The issue is that a "scan()" function result from the iPhone gives me several devices nearby, but not mine...in Android it works great off course!

What am I missing? Is there a way to make it discover-able?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use an app like LightBlue.app (available on the AppStore), do you see your device? If Yes, you may want to show us the Cordova code rather the Python one.

Comment: @Larme No, I can't see my device using LightBlue...

Comment: At the bottom of the thread in the link below there is an example using dbus to place an interface in discoverable mode. I'll test this and write up an answer when I can (if it works); Unless someone beats me to it. Just wanted to post a possible path forward: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=111486

Comment: @jinksPadlock that'l be great. Thanks

Comment: are you using Bluetooth 4.0+ LE? ( https://fretlight.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/210215093-How-Do-I-Know-If-My-iOS-Device-Is-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-Enabled- )

Comment: @tiagoperes yes

Comment: have a look at this link here, is Python interface to Bluetooth LE on Linux:

 http://ianharvey.github.io/bluepy-doc/

Comment: @tiagoperes I've tried that before. It consists of connecting to other peripherals or services, I would like to advertise one (e.g. I want to be the device to connect to, not from...)

Comment: ah ok. Check Pybluez, there's a script to for detecting nearby Bluetooth devices, check in the examples (https://code.google.com/archive/p/pybluez/wikis/Documentation.wiki )

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

iOS filter the Bluetooth profiles, and the RFCOMM (aka Bluetooth Serial Port Profile) is not supported. Here is the list of the [iOS Supported Bluetooth profiles](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387) from Apple itself.

And yes, it's a shame, we know that's working perfectly on Desktop and Android, but you can't do the same on iOS :)

Comment: Is there a way to create Bluetooth socket, using Python, of the kind iOS supports?

Comment: Nop. I remember that there is some devices that can be plugged to audio and give bluetooth spp capability, using a specific framework. Try google :)

Comment: ios has explicit support for RFCOMM and recommends using it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html